# Remove all elements in Linked List

Tags: c, list, linked-list

```
temp = Head;
while (Head != NULL) {
    Head = temp->nextPtr;
    free(temp);
}
```

In my project, I use temporary linked list and I want to remove all elements in linked list at the same time but compiler give Segmentation Fault.

Comment: in your code, you keep freeing the same node, dont you? I mean, temp pointer does not change at all inside the while loop.

Comment: this just sample code , none of them not work

Answer (score 6):

You are missing `temp=Head;` somewhere there, at the beginning or end of the loop... temp stays on the first head.

The easiest is to move `temp=Head;` from before the loop to the first line inside the loop.

```
while (Head != NULL) {
    temp = Head;
    Head = temp->nextPtr;
    free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your compiler is giving `Segmentation Fault`. It shouldn't segfault, even under pretty horrible inputs. I think your *program* is causing the segfault: you've neglected to set `temp` within the body of your loop.